# Meteor multiple mongo update operator in a single statement

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update my mongo collocation with multiple mongo update operators in a single statement, it's currently not working and only doing the first operator.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
Organizations.update({_id:adminOrg._id}, {$push: {users:id}},{$inc: {usersCount: 1}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [modifier](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/modifiers) needs to be a single object:

```js
Organizations.update(adminOrg._id,
  {$push: {users:id}, $inc: {usersCount: 1}}
);
```

Comment: Thanks wasn't paying attention to the syntax